# How to make an installer without window, running in the background in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I need to make an installer to provide updates to a certain program, 
I need the installer to run in the background so the user will not know about it so he will net be aware about exiting from it,

What should I do?

Thanks :)

---

edited ...

---

Thanks all, I found the answer :)
putting

```
SetSilent silent
```

in a section or a function will solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetSilent` can toggle the state at runtime but if the installer is always silent it is better to use the SilentInstall attribute: `SilentInstall silent`